# Time difference in hours of a column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
id  time_taken
1   2017-06-21 07:36:53
2   2017-06-21 07:32:28
3   2017-06-22 08:55:09
4   2017-06-22 08:04:31
5   2017-06-21 03:38:46
```

`current_time =  2017-06-22 10:08:16`

i want to create  df2 where time difference of time_taken columns is greater than 24 hours with current_time

i.e

```
1   2017-06-21 07:36:53
2   2017-06-21 07:32:28
5   2017-06-21 03:38:46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `Timedelta` to [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and compare or compare with `Timedelta`, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
current_time = '2017-06-22 10:08:16'

df['time_taken'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_taken'])
```

---

```
df = df[(pd.to_datetime(current_time) - df['time_taken']).dt.total_seconds() > 60 * 60 * 24]
print (df)
   id          time_taken
0   1 2017-06-21 07:36:53
1   2 2017-06-21 07:32:28
4   5 2017-06-21 03:38:46
```

Or:

```
df = df[(pd.to_datetime(current_time) - df['time_taken']) > pd.Timedelta(24, unit='h')]
print (df)
   id          time_taken
0   1 2017-06-21 07:36:53
1   2 2017-06-21 07:32:28
4   5 2017-06-21 03:38:46
```

Comment: the datatype of df['time_taken'][0] = 'str' so it is showing me error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'`