# How can i find difference between two Pandas date time object in AM /PM format

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data from a csv file.  Two columns have date time values like `12/08/2017 17:17:48` and I wanted to convert it in to AM/PM.  I read from below links and converted both column in to proper format (AM/PM).

[link1](http://hamelg.blogspot.com/2015/11/python-for-data-analysis-part-17.html), 
[link2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

I used following commands:

```
data3['Occurred On (NT) AM PM']=pd.to_datetime(data3['Occurred On (NT)']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S:%p')
data3['Cleared On (NT) AM PM']=pd.to_datetime(data3['Cleared On (NT)']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S:%p')
```

Now I want the difference between these two columns. I used following command:

```
data3['diff']=data3['Occurred On (NT) AM PM']-data3['Cleared On (NT) AM PM']
```

and it gave me an error

> "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'"

It was suggested in an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691778/time-difference-in-hours-of-a-column-of-pandas-dataframe) to convert the column to a date time object. So, I tried the following:

```
data3['Cleared On (NT) AM PM']=pd.to_datetime(data3['Cleared On (NT) AM PM'])
```

and it gave me this error:

> "Unknown string format"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess you're looking for `data3['diff']=data3['Occurred On (NT)']-data3['Cleared On (NT)']`

Comment: Further clarification: When you use stftime you are converting a datetime object to a string. You need to substract first and then do the strftime.

Comment: ok i will try that.

Comment: Also is there a ways to get the difference in  hours only